# Limit ordinal in the exponent

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

How would you prove that $$n^{\gamma} = m^{\gamma}$$ for every limit ordinal $\gamma$ and $n,m$ finite ordinals?

It's a rather short solution problem, but I can't construct any slick answer for it. I know very little about ordinal exponentiation, just that $\alpha^{\beta +1} = \alpha^{\beta}\cdot\alpha$ and that if there's a limit ordinal in the exponent we take the $\sup$.

Comment: That was ***LITERALLY*** the first question in the [ordinals] tag at the time when you posted your question.

Comment: Yeah that's one of the questions in a problem's list in a set theory class at my Uni, seems I'm not the only one having trouble with it ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to assume that $m,n>1$.

First show that it’s true for $\gamma=\omega$. Then show that if it’s true for some limit $\gamma$, it’s true for $\gamma+\omega$; this is actually a bit like the first step. Finally, show that if it’s true for every limit ordinal less than $\gamma$, and $\gamma$ is a limit of limit ordinals, then it’s true for $\gamma$ as well.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I forgot about this assumption!